# Store array of pointers in array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of pointers and I want to temporarily store the contents into another array of pointers but I'm not sure how, everything gives me segmentation fault.

Something like:

```
char *records[6], *temp[6];

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    fgets(temp[i], 999, fp); // Filling array with opened file line by line
    records[i]=temp[i];
}
```

When I use *temp instead, records gets entirely filled with only the last line of my file instead.

Comment: Its a typo; you need to do `i++` not `i+` in your for-loop!

Comment: @rndm  Where are you going to read 999 bytes using the statement fgets(temp[i], 999, fp);?

Comment: You can't read data from fp into temp[i] when temp[i] doesn't actually point to any allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to allocate memory for each line you read in. Note that your array `char *temp[6]` reserves memory for 6 pointers, but it does not reserve any memory for the place to which these pointers will point to. So every member of `temp`, e.g. the first one `temp[0]`, points to somewhere where you are not allowed to write to. Hence, already the first `fgets(temp[i], 999, fp)` will yield undefined behaviour, very likely a segfault.

To solve the problem, read in into a buffer, and then reserve memory according to the length of the line and copy the contents:

```
char *records[6] = { 0 };
char buffer[999];

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    if (fgets(buffer, 999, fp) == NULL)
       break;

    records[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
    strcpy (records[i], buffer);
}
```

Note further that the return value of `fgets`, which is `NULL` in case of an error like `EOF` reached, should be considered. Also the typo `i++` instead of `i+` is corrected.

Comment: you're welcome. Please don't hesitate to accept the answer if it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate memory for the lines - currently the pointers in both arrays don't point to anything (further, they are unitialized, meaning their value is undefined).
You can do that dynamically (using `malloc`) or you could declare a 2d char array, in which each subarray (line) is a string.

```
char records[6][999] = { 0 }, temp[6][999] = { 0 };
...
```